# Google Colab cannot find kaggle.json

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, kaggle, fast-ai

I am working on a project inspired by Jeremy Howard's FastAi course and am stuck as google colab cannot locate kaggle.json in /root/.kaggle

What I've done so far:

1. Accept the rules at Kaggle and download an API token
2. Create a folder on my windows laptop under C:\Users\hardi and name it .kaggle
3. Place kaggle.json in said folder
4. Upload kaggle.json to google colab and run the following code: 

   `! mkdir .kaggle
   ! mv .kaggle /root/
   ! mv kaggle.json .kaggle`

as well as:

`! kaggle competitions download -c planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space -f train-jpg.tar.7z -p {path}

! kaggle competitions download -c planet-understanding-the-amazon-from-space -f train_v2.csv -p {path}

! unzip -q -n {path}/train_v2.csv.zip -d {path}`

What am I doing wrong? What should I be doing instead? Thank you.

Comment: Well you tell us, what is going wrong?

Comment: Would you be able to post all the code (in the exact order in the notebook) as well as the error itself (so we can know what line is producing the problem). From initial inspection, it looks like `!mv kaggle.json .kaggle` should throw an error, since you moved `.kaggle` to `/root` so it really should be `!mv kaggle.json /root/.kaggle`